# How to use the gradient for both :after and different section?

Tags: css

I'm trying to use the same gradient for two different sections. The top part is a `:after` from the blue div and I'd like to 'extend' the same gradient to combine both. Look at the image below.

[image: the :after without the gradient]

If I change the gray color for the same gradient, it won't be positioned in the same way. Also, if possible I'd like to know in case of a background image

This is the result I expect:
[image: both :after (from the blue div) and the gradient div together with the same gradient]

The CSS

```
.div1 {
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.div1:after {
    content: '';
    width: 150%;
    height: 220px;
    background: gray;
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -45px;
    left: -3px;
}
.div2 {
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  background: rgb(131,58,180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131,58,180,1) 0%, rgba(253,29,29,1) 50%, rgba(252,176,69,1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: What is your desired result exactly? Also, can you show the relevant code?

Comment: Hey! I only need the gradient with the gray part (the gray div is part of the blue section, just added it as :after to make this effect). So basically the gradient must be in both gray and the section that has already the gradient.

Comment: Search [Codepen](https://codepen.io/search/pens?q=slanted+border), It'll come to you... For use to help you, post a [reprex].

Comment: @RenevanderLende isnt it related to background path or something like this? I have no idea how to search it.

Comment: The problem is, we neither if you don't post a [reprex]. Alternatively I suggested Codepen.

Comment: I added there now, see if it helps. Tks :)

Comment: Have you tried setting `.div1` to `position: absolute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do like below:

```css
.div1 {
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
  height:100px;
}

.div1:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100px;
  background: inherit;
  transform-origin:left;
  transform:skewY(-4deg);
}

.div2 {
  padding-top: 90px;
  padding-bottom: 90px;
  background: rgb(131, 58, 180);
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(131, 58, 180, 1) 0%, rgba(253, 29, 29, 1) 50%, rgba(252, 176, 69, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="div2"></div>
```